# Zend Framework 2, redirecting to route and passing a variable to new controller

Tags: php, forms, redirect, routes, zend-framework2

I implemented a form for placing new orders in Zend Framework 2 and after submitting the form I should redirect to another route and take the `orders.id` variable in another controller.

I tried using `$this->redirect()->toRoute('confirm', array('param'=>$orderId));` but it is not working at all.

Maybe I do not know how to get that parameter in another `confirmAction` controller.

Please give me some examples. Thank you very much.

Comment: Saying it's 'not working' tells us nothing of what's actually happening in your code. At a guess you're missing the `return` in your redirect call, it should be `return $this->redirect()->toRoute('confirm', array('param'=>$orderId));`, but it's just that, a guess. If you expect more help, provide the routing config for your `confirm` route and the portion of your controller action code which contains the redirect.

Comment: is it redirecting with the orders.id? if it does then $this->Params('param') will get you the id at the other controller. If is not redirecting with the param then you need to set your routing in module.config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Since this is a routing issue, show what you have for the route in the module.config.php file. You might not have the "param" constraint configured properly in your config if I had to guess.

It should look something like this:

```
'confirm' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'       => '/controller_name/confirm[/][:param][/]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'param' => '[0-9]*'
        ),

        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'your_namespace', // ex. Application\Controller
            'action'        => 'confirm', // or whatever action you're calling
            'controller'    => 'controller_name' // ex.
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Yessss.... :) Thank you very much... :) It is working now. Instead of using 'type' => 'literal' I should have gone with 'segment' + 'constraints'. Thank you again... :D